# Check if it's possible to go forward when using vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm developing an application using Vue2 and Vue-router (version ^2.2.0) and the back and forward navigation buttons have to show if the user can go back/forward or not.

To check if the user can go back it's simple: if the user is not at the home screen, he can.

The problem comes when checking whether or not the user can go forward, since I need to check the router's history, but I haven't been able to do so.

Is there a way to check if the router has "somewhere to go when calling router.go(1)"?

Comment: In the lastest release of `vue-router v2.2.0` there is `onComplete` and `onAbort` callbacks for `router.push` method, as the 2nd and 3rd arguments:
`router.push(location, onComplete, onAbort)`. I'm not 100% sure this will work, but you could try with these callbacks..

Comment: It wouldn't work since I would need those callbacks in router.go too.

Answer (score 0):

A web application? `router.go(n)` is `history.go(n)` so it's the same limitations as that. It would be unsafe to expose a persons history to a website. Also, just because they're home doesn't mean they can't go back and just because the user can go forward doesn't mean it'll navigate to something in your app. If you're trying to replicate the forward and back button you're going to have a bad time.

If it's not a web app then you'd need to manually track the users history and splice and replace and push just like the browser does.

Comment: It's not a web app, it's an hybrid app for Android, iOS, Windows and OSX. Why and what exactly should I "splice and replace and push"?

Comment: You'd need to keep an array of the history like `[ { path: '/foo', active: true|false } ]`. You'd push to it as you go to different paths and set the new entry as active. Then, when the back or forward button is pressed you'd need to `router.replace(nextUrl)` in the right direction and set active as true for it. However, since it's just an app you might not want a real back/forward browser behavior. Are you sure you don't want more like a "back/forward takes you through the breadcrumbs/hierarchy" type situation.

Comment: Right now the back button works as intended: it just calls router.go(-1) if the current screen it not the home screen. I'm not using router.replace anywhere. The method you are suggesting is to wrap the router and never call router.go isn't it?

Comment: Correct. `router.go` in `history.go`. You can tell it where to go but it can't tell you where it's going since it would be a security/privacy violation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the HTML5-history-mode configuration? Documentation can be found [here](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).

You may also need to enabled it in your server. If you're using express, I've got this line in my server code:

```
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());
```

Comment: I have the HTML5 history mode enabled, but AFAIK that doesn't allow me to check if there are routes to go when calling router.go(1)